# How to show/Hide for selected Li using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, show-hide

I have **UL** tag which contain **Li** with many `classnames`,
I want to `show` those Li whose `classname are same` and **hide** others.

Here the
**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satinder_singh1/m4VyA/)**

For example here If i click class1 then "John,Michle,Alex" will be visible rest all have to hide

**EDITED:**
Also Sort Li while hiding list

**ANSWER:**

By changing  `$(this).show();`  to 
 `$(this).parent('Li').show();` solved my blank space problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You made a simple error in your jsfiddle.
Here's a [fix](http://jsfiddle.net/m4VyA/1/).

I changed the line:

```
if ($('#emplistName Ul Li Span').hasClass(className) === true) {
```

to:

```
if ($(this).hasClass(className) === true) {
```

Comment: thanks for reply, its works fine , one more thing i want to do when its hide i want to fill those blank spaces, i mean sort those list

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use `.live()`, it's deprecated
2. Do not use `.each()`, it's unnecessary

```
$("ul.tagingUL li").on("click", function () {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#emplistName ul li span.'+className).show();
    $('#emplistName ul li span:not(.'+className+')').hide();
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/m4VyA/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for ur reply, I use .live() because my UL tag was under **asp:UpdatePanel** so on click is not working there